# "Same to" or "same as"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have asked a question at the programming site, but I am not sure about my grammar, so I am going to ask here. Which is correct?

> What are other languages **same to** F#?
>
> What are other languages **same as** F#?

Comment: Neither version is good English. I better way to phrase the question is *"What other languages are similar to F#?"*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the word "similar" instead of "same" in this case.

"What are other languages *similar to* F#?" (or better yet, "What other languages *are similar to* F#?") would be correct and convey your intended meaning.

The phrases "similar to" and "the same as" convey slightly different meanings. "The same as" indicates that two things are identical in some way, while "similar to" means that they differ only slightly.

(The phrase "same to" is simply incorrect.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to say 'What other languages are the same as F#?'

Answer (score 3):

The expression "same to" does not exist in any variety of English, as far as I know. "Same as" is grammatical.

But I think mblase75 is right. You could say "What languages are same as F# in their handling of ... ", i.e. the same in some specific respect; but the only language which is the same as F# in general is F#.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather say, "Is there any language similar to F#?" or perhaps "What are the languages similar to F#?".

But English is my second language. So you might want more opinions from others.

Answer (score 1):

'what other languages are same as F" is wrong as two different languages cant be same  but similar .Hence, you can say,"what other languages are similar to F".

Comment: This seems to be little more than a sampling of the previous answers.   Please don’t post an answer unless you have something new to contribute.