# Are there any dialects of English where it is possible to say 'same to' instead of 'same as'?

Tags: prepositions, colloquialisms, comparisons

"different" can be used colloquially by many speakers of English with either "than", "to" or "from".

Does anyone know of any varieties of English where people might say "same to"? For instance, younger speakers, bilingual speakers with a particular language, speakers from a particular region.

For instance: "That's the same bike to John's!" meaning "That's the same bike as John's!"

Update:

There is a previous question asking which is correct between 'same to' and 'same as': ["Same to" or "same as"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43487/same-to-or-same-as) . However neither of the sentences given there are correct, and both sentences appear to be written by a non-native speaker of English. I'm not asking which of 'same to' or 'same as' is more acceptable (the answer is 'same as') or whether 'same to' is grammatical or not (the answer is that it standardly isn't). I'm asking whether there are any varieties of English where 'same to' is possible. To be clearer, this isn't an ESL question, it's an English dialect/variation question.

Comment: "Goodbye, Fred.  Have a good day!"  "Same to you!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary describes "same to" as a "rare" and "obsolete" construction, and gives the following example:

> 1756   W. Toldervy *Hist. Two Orphans* III. 33   I am of the same
>   opinion to the gentleman, who spoke last.

I also checked Upton et al *Survey of English Dialects* but couldn't see anything relevant.